# Camel and ActiveMQ

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I´m very new on the camel world, that is why I´m asking for your help.
Let me tell you what I would like to do:
I have this basic Camel standalone project:

```
package maventest1;


public class JmsToSql {

private Main main;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JmsToSql example = new JmsToSql();
    example.boot();
}

    public void boot() throws Exception {
    main = new Main();
    main.enableHangupSupport();
    main.bind("foo", new MyBean());
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
    main.bind("test-jms",JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));
    main.addRouteBuilder(new MyRouteBuilder());
    main.run();
}

    private static class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("timer:foo?delay=2000")
            .process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                         //NOT SURE THIS IS THE RIGHT WAY
                           from("test-jms:queue:order1")
                           .to("test-jms:queue:order2");
                }
            })
            .beanRef("foo");
    }
}

public static class MyBean {
    public void callMe() {
        System.out.println("MyBean.calleMe method has been called");
    }
   }
 }
```

All I want to do is read all the messages from an activeMQ queue and pass them into another queue. Does anybody know how I can do this?
Thanks in advance =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a route from JMS to JMS

```
 private static class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
         from("test-jms:queue:order1")
            .to("test-jms:queue:order2");
    }
```

As you are new to Camel, I recommend to also read this article first

- http://java.dzone.com/articles/open-source-integration-apache

And if you want to have great documentation and tutorials, then pickup one of the Camel books

- http://camel.apache.org/books

Comment: I can´t believe I didn´t try this, It works like a charm!!. Thank you very much. Now, I just have to parse the messages (they´re xml format) and insert information into the database :D.